# Check Length of Data

Tags: php

Need help.
Scenario:

A data will be receive by my php script.
What i want is to check the data if it is less than or more than 160 characters.
If it is more than 160,the smsvalue will be 2 sms.If it is less than 160,the smsvalue will be 1.

I can create this logic,however
I want to be like this:
160 + 160 = 320 right?

```
if($data>160){
$smsvalue = '1';
}elseif($data->320){
    $smsvalue = '2';    
    }elseif($data->480){
    $smsvalue = '3';    
}
```

Is there any possible way to check it by loop?
because the checking  i made is hardcoded only.

Thanks

Comment: [strlen — Get string length](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just divide the length by 160, and then use ceil to round up to the nearest whole number (ex: 480/160 = 3, 481/160 = 4)

```
$length = strlen($data);
$smsvalue = ceil($length/160);
```

Comment: I try to run this code,however my data length is 340,but i got 3 smsvalue.I expected that this will be 2 smsvalue only

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question then.  Wouldn't you want it to be 3? 160 in message 1, 160 in message 2, 20 in message 3.  You can use floor to round down to nearest whole number.  $smsvalue = floor($length/160)